# Forcing a tab to the next control in an extended .net control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, controls

Say I'm extending a TextBox called CustomTextBox in .net. In certain situations I would like to force a tab to the next TabIndex on the form. Is there a way to do this beyond getting all the controls contained in CustomTextBox's parent, sorting them by their TabIndex, and then focusing the next ordinal one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like the following method:

```
form1.SelectNextControl(textBox1, true, true, true, true);
```

(All the trues are just different options, read the intellisense!)

You did say it is WinForms and not WebForms right?

Answer (score 0):

If you're extending a normal Winforms Textbox, you can set the **AcceptsTab** property to True or False, depending on your needs. If it's true, then a tab character will be inserted into your textbox. If it's false, then hitting the Tab key will move focus to the next control in the Tab Order

Comment: I think EMaddox84 meant how does he 'programmatically' force a tab, not how does he set up his controls to accept tabs.